# Next js dynamic API call with Express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an express server set up like so:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    fetch('https://api.adzuna.com:443/v1/api/property/gb/search/1?app_id=1cd4129d&app_key=key&where=se16bx&distance=5&category=for-sale')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
          res.send(data) // Prints result from `response.json()` in getRequest
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
  });
```

I then have a Next.js page like so:

```
class About extends Component {
  state = {postcode: null}

  handleOnSubmit = e => {
      // calling the api passing the postcode
  }

  render() {
   return(
    <form>
      <input name="postcode" />
      <button onClick={this.handleOnSubmit}></button>
    </form>
   )
  }
}

About.getInitialProps = async function() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/');
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    results: data
  }
}
```

the API call in the Express server has a hard coded postcode in it.

> where=se16bx

How can I pass that value in a dynamic way based on what the user will put into the form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create dynamic API call, for complete documentation you can see from [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/custom-server-express/server.js) (Check `/posts` API).

In your case, you just need to add slug into your endpoint, then pass it to your fetcher function:

```
app.get('/:id*', (req, res) => {
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    fetch(`https://api.adzuna.com:443/v1/api/property/gb/search/1?app_id=1cd4129d&app_key=key&where=${req.params.id}&distance=5&category=for-sale`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
          res.send(data) // Prints result from `response.json()` in getRequest
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
  });
```